# How to scan a complete Symfony project for dependencies?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am working on a Symfony 2.7 project. I ran `composer update --dry-run` to check which packages could need an update. Composer notified me about a deprecated package:

> Package symfony/icu is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use
>   symfony/intl instead.

I simply removed the dependency from the `composer.json` file and ran `composer update --dry-run` again. The message did not show up again, `symfony/icu` was uninstalled and `symfony/intl` was not installed.

Fine, this means that non of the other requirements depends on `symfony/icu` or `symfony/intl`. **But can I be sure, that non of my own code requires any of these packages?**

I created the project white a while ago and I do not remember why I added `symfony/icu`. I is possible, that the code that once required this packages has been removed, but I am not sure.

I used `grep` to search for any import of `symfony/icu` and found nothing. However that does not guarantee, that the package is not uses somewhere within my code, does it?

Is there any way to check if there are any dependencies within the **complete** Symfony project that require a specific package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way is to start with `composer` and tell it dump all packages that caused your package to install:

- For example, I'm trying to figure out why `monolog/monolog` is installed:

  ```
  $ composer depends monolog/monolog
  symfony/monolog-bundle  2.11.1  requires  monolog/monolog (~1.18)
  ```

  So `monolog/monolog` was installed because of `symfony/monolog-bundle`.
- As you said you might have unintentionally use a package that's a dependency of another package so you didn't add it to your dependencies.

  I'd use `grep` just as you did to search my source code. Just note that it's better to search for an actual class name, not the package name. Searching for package name would give you `composer.json` files but that's easier to analyze with `composer depends` than `grep`:

  ```
  $ grep  --include=\*.php -rnw './vendor' -e 'use Monolog'
  ./vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/ErrorHandler.php:16:use Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler;
  ./vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/ChromePHPFormatter.php:14:use Monolog\Logger;
  ./vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/FluentdFormatter.php:45:            throw new \RuntimeException('PHP\'s json extension is required to use Monolog\'s FluentdUnixFormatter');
  ./vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/GelfMessageFormatter.php:14:use Monolog\Logger;
  ./vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/HtmlFormatter.php:13:use Monolog\Logger;
  ./vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/NormalizerFormatter.php:34:            throw new \RuntimeException('PHP\'s json extension is required to use Monolog\'s NormalizerFormatter');
  ./vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/WildfireFormatter.php:14:use Monolog\Logger;
  ```

  This command searches all `*.php` files and dups also line numbers containing `Monolog`.

Unfortunately, the these two methods just analyze your code post-mortem. Really the best way to avoid dealing with this is to write unit tests. Then clone your fresh repository, install dependencies with `composer install` and run tests. This should guarantee that your code is run in isolation from any other unwanted dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

### Check for every package? :(

I think you can do this only with automated testing.

There are no tools (I'm aware of) to detect whether some package is required to complete missing classes. There are also optional dependencies (package works without them, but with them will add some new features), so you will find missing classes but not required to run application.

---

### How to check one package? :)

You heading right direction with `grep`. **Yet rather look for namespace instead of package name**. Package name is not always 1:1 to package namespace.

I would look for:

- repo on Github: https://github.com/symfony/icu
- open some file: https://github.com/symfony/icu/blob/1.2.x/IcuRegionBundle.php
- find namespace

  ```
  namespace Symfony\Component\Icu;
  ```
- then search for "Symfony\Component\Icu" in code in PhpStorm or `grep`